# Python pandas sorting column data frame keeping other columns fixed

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a table in .csv which contains data over the time. I upload it in the following way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```

And I get

```
A       time               USER
1    2014-03-03 08:24:53    a
1    2014-03-03 08:25:55    a
1    2014-03-03 08:26:50    a
1    2014-03-03 07:17:02    a 
1    2014-03-03 08:28:17    a
1    2014-03-03 08:32:12    a
2    2014-03-03 08:36:01    a
2    2014-03-03 08:38:14    a
2    2014-03-03 07:28:45    a
2    2014-03-03 08:44:03    a
2    2014-03-03 08:50:29    a
2    2014-03-03 07:40:50    a
2    2014-03-03 07:41:17    a
2    2014-03-03 08:56:31    a
2    2014-03-03 08:57:47    a
```

I want to sort the column `time` keeping fixed the other columns

```
A       time               USER
1    2014-03-03 07:17:02    a 
1    2014-03-03 08:24:53    a
1    2014-03-03 08:25:55    a
1    2014-03-03 08:26:50    a
1    2014-03-03 08:28:17    a
1    2014-03-03 08:32:12    a
2    2014-03-03 07:28:45    a
2    2014-03-03 07:40:50    a
2    2014-03-03 07:41:17    a
2    2014-03-03 08:36:01    a
2    2014-03-03 08:38:14    a
2    2014-03-03 08:44:03    a
2    2014-03-03 08:50:29    a
2    2014-03-03 08:56:31    a
2    2014-03-03 08:57:47    a
```

Comment: Judging from your output it looks like you want to do `df.sort(columns=['A','time'])`

Comment: Solved. It now works!

Comment: Your solution works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your desired output it looks like what you want to do is [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort) on multiple columns:

```
df.sort(columns=['A','time'])
```

Here it sorts first on column 'A' and then 'time'